# Is the zero polynomial a homogenous polynomial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I think this is just tying up a definition for me, but the definition I have for homogeneous polynomial is that all its non-zero terms have the same degree so what happens in the case of the zero polynomial?

Comment: I don't get this definition. Can you give me an example of an non-homogeneous polynomial?

Comment: It is just a matter of definitions, of course. But if you want that the space of homogeneous polynomials is a vector space with the standard operations, you must include the zero polynomial.

Comment: @GitGud $p(x,y)=x^2+xy$.

Comment: As the comment by @GiuseppeNegro shows, you can consider it to be homogeneous, but its degree is not well defined. In fact, it has every degree, in the sense that $f(ax)=a^n f(x)$ for every $n$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich The polynomial you mention *is* homogeneous

Comment: @GitGud Sorry, missed the "non". The polynomial $p(x)=x^2+x$ is non-homogeneous.

Comment: @thedude : I think that, by convention, the zero polynomial is assumed to have degree $-\infty $, to deal with that.

Comment: @thedude I edited the comment, David read the first version of it.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich My bad, I edited the comment before you replied. I completly forgot about polynomials on more than one variable. I just kept thinking that all polynomials are non-homogenous.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro But we want the space of degree-$n$ homogeneous  polynomials to be a vector space, for every $n$

Answer (score 0):

If you want the space of degree-$n$ homogeneous polynomials to be a vector space, for every $n$, which is the usual convention, then yes you must consider the zero polynomial to be homogeneous. Moreover, you must consider it to be homogeneous of every degree. This is a bit strange but acceptable as it indeed satisfies $f(ax)=a^n f(x)$ for every $n$.